# Selenium Webdriver doesn't open Firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I start a script with Selenium-Webdriver, the Firefox window that I expect to open never opens. This code used to work, but no longer does:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

p "DEFINING `driver`"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
p "OPENING GOOGLE"
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Selenium Tutorials"
element.submit

driver.quit
```

When I run it, "DEFINING `driver`" prints to the console, but the script just hangs there.

The only major thing I did in the past 48 hours was run a virus scan.

Comment: What version of Firefox and Selenium-Webdriver did you have?

Comment: Right now: Firefox v36.0.1 and Selenium-Webdriver v2.44.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your Selenium-Webdriver gem to version 2.45.0

Comment: This did not fix on Ubuntu 14.04